# Assign a user input value from a loop to different registers in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers

The question goes like this: 1. Print the following message: "Enter an integer"
2. Read the input 3. Do this for 5 times 4. Check for the valid input. Repeat the process again for invalid input 5. Calculate the value of P * Q - ( R + S * T). 6. Print P * Q - ( R + S * T) = X.

I am confused on how to assign the user input from the loop to a different register for every new loop iteration.

This is my code:

```
 .data
msg1: .asciiz "Please enter an integer:"
.align 2
array: .space 100

.text
main:
    la $t3 array
    loop:

        la $a0, msg1 #output message
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
        li $v0, 5 #read in user input
        syscall
        move $t0, $v0
        beq  $t1,5, endloop #get user input up to 5 times 



        b loop #loop until it reaches 5 

    endloop:

    jr $ra
```

Comment: _"I am confused on how to assign the user input from the loop to a different register for every new loop iteration."_ Self-modifying code! No but seriously, why not store the values in memory instead?

Comment: Well, how do you do that? Also need to compare those values. I am confused here.

Comment: You've already assigned `$t3` the base address of `array` (except that there's a missing comma on that line). So inside the loop you can just do `sw $v0,($t3)`, and then `addiu $t3,$t3,4` to make `$t3` point to the next element in the array.

Comment: Got that. Thanks. And how do you access the value stored in the array?

Comment: With the `lw` instruction.